# Limit same Random number JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, discord.js

im selecting a statement from a json file, but the one i get is done by a randome number, but i want to avoid getting the same one consecutive times, is there a way to limit this?

Right now this is the code i have for that part, it gives me a random question beetween the amounth of questions i have

```
        const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('quiz.json'));
        const quizNum =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 22);
```

i was thinking something to avoid getting the same question if it was given in the last 2 or 3 times

Comment: The safest strategy would be to generate an array of consecutive numbers and shuffle it. You can then take the elements from that, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an array to keep track of the recent questions and adjust with a variable the length of that array

```
const recentQuestions = []
const maxRecentQuestions = 3
```

and then do a function that will check if the new question is in the array of recentQuestions

and if yes, proceed by doing a

```
recentQuestions.shift()
```

to remove the oldest question in recentQuestions

and push the new question with a

```
recentQuestions.push(newQuestion)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet, demonstrating how you can pick some random questions, based on a shuffled index array:

```js
function shfl(a){ // Durstenfeld shuffle
 for(let j,i=a.length;i>1;){
  j=Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
  if (i!=j) [a[i],a[j]]=[a[j],a[i]]
 }
 return a
}

// define a questions array named quiz:
const quiz=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q"]; // 17 elements ...
// instead of shuffling the array itself I am generating
// an index array which I will use for picking "random" questions:
const idx=shfl(quiz.map((_,i)=>i));
// ... and now I will pick some 5 non-repeating random questions:
console.log(idx.slice(0,5).map(i=>quiz[i]));
```